# Ruby on Rails cannot load such file -- selenium-webdriver Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am testing running selenium webdriver with phantomjs from Ruby on Rails. I am testing locally on my computer.

The following code runs fine within my test Ruby script when I run "ruby test.rb"

```
  def google_title
    require 'selenium-webdriver'
    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs
    driver.navigate.to "https://www.google.com"
    page_title = driver.title
    puts page_title
  end

  google_title
```

I have pretty much the same code in my application_controller.rb file:

```
  def google_title
    require 'selenium-webdriver'
    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs
    driver.navigate.to "https://www.google.com"
    page_title = driver.title
    render text: page_title
  end
```

But when I run my app I get a "cannot load such file -- selenium-webdriver" error.

[image]

I have added this to my Gemfile and ran bundle install but get the same error.

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.45'
```

When I run gem list --local it shows selenium is installed.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

I ran almost exactly the same code as above but with watir-webdriver and got the same results. The Ruby script ran fine by it's self but gave a "cannot load such file" error for watir-webdriver when I tried to run it from Rails.

I ran another test with nokogiri and it worked fine. Both by it's self and in Rails.

**Update2:**

It appears to be something I am doing and not my test environment. I just ran the same code on an online IDE and got the same type of error:

[image]

**Update3:**

Here is the full content of the application_controller.rb file when I run the test with watir-webdriver and headless. I get the same results. Maybe I am setting something wrong here?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def google_title
    require 'watir-webdriver'
    require 'headless'
    headless = Headless.new
    headless.start
    b = Watir::Browser.start 'www.google.com'
    page_title = b.title
    b.close
    headless.destroy
    render text: page_title
  end
end
```

[image]

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this issue. I tried the exact same steps and installed `selenium-webdriver` version `2.53.0` and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Strange. I added the full content of the application_controller.rb file just to make sure I am not missing something simple.

Comment: https://github.com/firangistan/webdriver-test Check if this application works for you.

Comment: are you using any version manager? have you try bundle update?

Answer (score 0):

did you restart your webrick, puma ...server?

works like a charm.

`gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.45'`

`bundle install`

on mac:

`brew install phantomjs`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  #no need for require
  def google_title
    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs
    driver.navigate.to "https://www.google.com"
    page_title = driver.title
    render text: page_title
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

`get 'google-title' => 'application#google_title'`

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/google-title
```

result Google